# Golang complexed function hooking using C in linux

Tags: c, linux, go, linux-kernel, rhel

There is a library in C I would like to use in a code written in Golang.
My product is about efficient, and I compared using this library with cgo to the code we currently have and found out that the current code is better, because of cgo inefficiency (i call this functions tons of time).
I was thinking of implementing my own way of calling the c functions and thought of this idea;
compile the c library to .so, load the .so into my product, and adding to my product's code some functions with the same signature as the functions I would like to use in the C library, than hook the go functions so when calling them the C functions will be called (using jump instruction).

I wrote a project just to test this idea. There is a doDis function which is written in go, and there is a addTwoNums with the same signature written in C. expected behavior is that when I call the doDis function the addTwoNums will be called. This is the code:

```golang
package main

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -ldl

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define LOG_FILE "LogFile.txt"
#define LENGTH_REPLACED 21
#define REPLACED_TEXT_A "HACKED - HOOK SUCCEED"
#define REPLACED_TEXT_W L"HACKED - HOOK SUCCEED"
#define STATUS_SUCCESS 0x00000000

char* format_string(const char* format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    // Determine the length of the formatted string
    va_list tmp_args;
    va_copy(tmp_args, args);
    int len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, tmp_args);
    va_end(tmp_args);

    // Allocate memory for the string
    char* str = malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if (!str) {
        // Handle malloc failure...
        va_end(args);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Format the string
    vsprintf(str, format, args);

    // Shrink the memory
    str = realloc(str, (len + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if (!str) {
        // Handle realloc failure...
        va_end(args);
        return NULL;
    }

    va_end(args);
    return str;
}

struct HookData
{
    void (*address)();
    char bytes[13];
    char hookBytes[13];
};

struct HookData hooks[10]; // Assuming a maximum of 10 hooks

typedef void (*voidFunc)();

void writeLog(const char *message)
{
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tm_info = localtime(&now);

    FILE *logFile = fopen(LOG_FILE, "a");
    if (logFile != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(logFile, "[%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d] %s\n",
                tm_info->tm_year + 1900, tm_info->tm_mon + 1, tm_info->tm_mday,
                tm_info->tm_hour, tm_info->tm_min, tm_info->tm_sec, message);
        fclose(logFile);
    }
}

int doHook(voidFunc hookedFunction, void (*functionToHook)(), const char *procName)
{
    writeLog("Hooking started.");
    char* str = format_string("replacing %p process's memory to call function in address %p", hookedFunction, functionToHook);
    writeLog(str);
    free(str);
    char functionOriginalBytes[13] = {0};
    char functionNewBytes[13] = {0};
    struct HookData currHook;

    // Get the page size
    long pageSize = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);

    // Calculate the aligned address to the page boundary
    uintptr_t alignedAddress = ((uintptr_t)functionToHook / pageSize) * pageSize;

    // Open the process memory file
    pid_t pid = getpid();

    char* pidStr = format_string("current process id is: %d", pid);
    writeLog(pidStr);
    free(pidStr);

    // Attach to the process
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, 0, 0) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error attaching to process");
        return 0;
    }

    // Wait for the process to stop
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);

    // Read original function bytes
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, pid, alignedAddress, functionOriginalBytes) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error reading function bytes");
        return 0;
    }

    // Create new function bytes
    uintptr_t offset = (uintptr_t)hookedFunction - (uintptr_t)functionToHook - 5;
    memcpy(functionNewBytes, "\xE9", 1);      // JMP opcode
    memcpy(functionNewBytes + 1, &offset, 4); // Relative jump offset
    memset(functionNewBytes + 5, 0x90, 8);   // NOP instructions for padding

    // Write the new function bytes
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_POKEDATA, pid, alignedAddress, *(long*)functionNewBytes) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error writing function bytes");
        return 0;
    }

    // Save hook information
    memcpy(currHook.bytes, functionOriginalBytes, sizeof(functionOriginalBytes));
    memcpy(currHook.hookBytes, functionNewBytes, sizeof(functionNewBytes));
    currHook.address = (void (*)())functionToHook;
    hooks[0] = currHook;

    // Detach from the process
    ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, 0, 0);

    writeLog("Hooking done.");

    return 1; // Success
}

int undoHook(void (*originalFunctionAddress)(), const char *functionOriginalBytes)
{
    // Open the process memory file
    pid_t pid = getpid();

    // Attach to the process
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, 0, 0) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error attaching to process");
        return 0;
    }

    // Wait for the process to stop
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);

    // Write back the original bytes
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_POKEDATA, pid, (uintptr_t)originalFunctionAddress, *(long*)functionOriginalBytes) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error writing original bytes");
        return 0;
    }

    // Detach from the process
    ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, 0, 0);

    writeLog("Writing original bytes done.");

    return 1; // Success
}

void addTwoNums(int a, int b)
{
    char* tmp = format_string("%d + %d = %d", a, b, a + b);
    writeLog(tmp);
    free(tmp);
}
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

func doDis(a int, b int) {
    fmt.Println(a)
    fmt.Println(b)
}

func main() {
    doDisAddress := reflect.ValueOf(doDis).Pointer()
    doDisFunction := (*[0]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(doDisAddress))
    C.doHook((C.voidFunc)(C.addTwoNums), doDisFunction, C.CString("doDis"))
    doDis(1, 2)
}
```

The problem is when running this code with sudo (and without) results in:

```
Error attaching to process: Operation not permitted
1
2
```

This is the log file:

```
[2023-12-01 17:10:34] Hooking started.
[2023-12-01 17:10:34] replacing 0x4813c0 process's memory to call function in address 0x480b60
[2023-12-01 17:10:34] current process id is: 8141
```

**My product is built for linux only**

I've tried running on both wsl and Rhel 8 but still no success, I ran `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`, I even thought of rebuilding the kernel as mentioned in some forums.

Comment: You're doing [effectively] `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH,getpid(),...)` A tracer can't trace itself. And, usually, the tracee pid has to [ultimately] be a child of the tracer. Otherwise, the `waitpid` won't work. But, **WHY** are you trying to use `ptrace` at all? You could [more] easily just call (using the standard binding) a C function that patches the go func. No need to use `ptrace` at all

Comment: This whole patch idea with `jmp` is [highly] suspect anyway (A `jmp` doesn't do arg conversion). Why not just use the standard go-to-C binding mechanism? If too many cross-lang calls, change the API so that you stay in C longer (e.g. rewrite some of the upper go code into C). _I was thinking of implementing my own way of calling the c functions_ Again, **why**? Do you really think you can come up with a faster binding?

Comment: And, I see _no_ reason to be patching the [linux] kernel here. And, I say that as someone who writes kernel code and device drivers. Is the issue that you're trying to contort `ptrace` in some fashion (to get it to work for the patching)? I really think you should _edit_ your question and explain in more detail what the C lib code does, why you think you need a special calling mechanism? If it's speed, show the code and benchmark results.

Comment: The C library I want to load is f stack. I need to call the send and receive functions constantly at high rate. The thing is I don't know if I could make it faster than cgo, but I do know that cgo isn't fast enough for me. I'm using ptrace because in order to write to the memory i need to remove it's protections, and if its ptrace i don't. My original code used mmap on the function to replace memory, but mmap also gave me operation not permitted.

Comment: I think we have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/785231) `libfstack` is a network "kernel bypass" library. Remember that I said: _If too many cross-lang calls, change the API so that you stay in C longer (e.g. rewrite some of the upper go code into C)_ I've done high speed kernel bypass network implementations before (with multiple threads doing processing, based on the message "type", with nanosecond resolution timestamping). You should implement the "main loop" that does many send/recv in C.